# persist several OneToMany relationships with JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have 4 entities related with OneToMany Realtionship with JPA . I m confused on how to persist in the entities .What is the correct way to persist this 4 entities (I don t want to use cascade.persist).I use Spring and Hibernate.  I will put only relevant fields in my entities to make it simple.

Response Entity :

```
@Entity
public class Response{
@Id 
private long responseID;
@OneToManye(mappedBy="response")
List <Income> incomes;
}
```

Income entity :

```
  @Entity
    public class Income{
    @Id 
    private long incomeID;
    @ManytoOne
    JoinColumn(name="RESPONSE_ID")
    private Response response;
    @OneToManye(mappedBy="income")
    List <IncomeBlock> incomeBlocks;
    }
```

IncomeBlock entity :

```
 @Entity
    public class IncomeBlock{
    @Id 
    private long incomeBlockID;
    @ManytoOne
    JoinColumn(name="INCOME_ID")
    private Income income;
    @OneToManye(mappedBy="incomeBlock")
    List <IncomeDetail> incomeDetails;
    }
```

IncomeDetail entity :

```
 @Entity
    public class IncomeDetail{
    @Id 
    private long incomeDetailID;
    @ManytoOne
    JoinColumn(name="INCOME_BLK_ID")
    private IncomeBlock incomeBlock;
    }
```

thank you guys for your help .
so far I tried 2 methods :

create incomeDetail :

```
IncomeBlock incomeBlock=new IncomeBlock ();
 em.persist (incomeBlock);
 IncomeDetail incomeDetail=new IncomeDetail ();
 incomeBlock.addIncomeDetail(incomeDetail);
 em.persist(incomeDetail);
```

create incomeBlock  :

```
 IncomeBlock incomeBlock=new IncomeBlock ();
 Income income=new Income();
 em.persist (income);
 IncomeDetail incomeBlock=new IncomeBlock ();
 income.addIncomeBlock(incomeBlock);
 em.persist(incomeDetail);
```

I tried this 2 methods so far and that doesn't  persist in database .

Comment: if you dont want to cascade then you call `persist` on every object to persist ... and what have you tried ? Why no fix the mapping errors too, while you're at it ... a `mappedBy` points to a field at the other side of the relation, and there is no "income" in `IncomeDetail`, and there is no "incomeDetail" in `IncomeDetail` ...

Comment: I update what I tried so far.

Comment: Sorry , it was a mistake for incomeDetails in IncomeDetail. but I don t understand the other suggestion income in IncomeDetail.

Comment: you have a "mappedBy" set to "income" on field `IncomeBlock.incomeDetails`, and that field does not exist in `IncomeDetail` ... its is called `incomeBlock`. And you say something doesn't persist ... but don't make any reference to TRANSACTIONs or the LOG, so then you see what DOES happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to persists OneToMany relation with your entity, you need to define `cascadeType` while declaring the relation. e.g.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="income")
List <IncomeBlock> incomeBlocks;
```

For details please refer https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html

If you don't want to use `cascade`, you can try below snippet of code :

```
 Income income=new Income();
 IncomeBlock incomeBlock=new IncomeBlock ();
 IncomeDetail incomeDetail=new IncomeDetail ();
 incomeBlock.addIncomeDetail(incomeDetail);
 income.addIncomeBlock(incomeBlock);
 em.persist(income);
```

Comment: I don t want to use cascade . because I m using entities of other team so I can not change but I want to do it manually